# 2D Canvas : specify `arc()` radius units

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, responsive-design, units-of-measurement

*I have been trying to make a responsive website which includes a canvas.*

While drawing a circular progress bar, am invoking the [`arc()`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp) function, but its `radius` argument, looks like it needs to be in pixels, but I would need it as percents, vw, vh, em or any other unit css proposes.

Of course, I could render it in pixels and stretch it using CSS, but it will either be upscaled and pixelated, downscaled and be a waste of resources, or otherwise distorted.

**How should I do it?**

Answer (score 1):

**After some searching, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript) which helped me solve the problem.**

Here's how I did it :

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

var vw = w/100;
var vh = h/100;

var pxradius = 50;
var vwradius = pxradius*vw;
```

*unfortunately, I still have no solution for percents and ems*

Comment: It seems to me, that your code exactly converts percentage value of `pxradius` into pixel value. So it is a solution for percents. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Well, not really, as percents are relative to the container in which the element is placed (afaik) and here it is only relative to the window height/width

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something right now, where I had to solve the exact same problem (i.e. setting radius values for [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) in percents or ems).

---

Here is JavaScript code of my solution:

```
function percentToPixelParentBased(percent, element, width_based=true) {
  return percentToPixelElementRelative(percent, element.parentElement, width_based);
}


function emToPixelParentBased(em_value, element) {
  return emToPixelElementRelative(em_value, element.parentElement);
}


function percentToPixelElementRelative(percent, element=false, width_based=true) { 
  if (element) {
    if (width_based) {
        var dimension = element.style.width || element.offsetWidth;
    } else {
        var dimension = element.style.height || element.offsetHeight; 
    }
  } else {
    if (width_based) {
        var dimension = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    } else {
        var dimension = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    }
  }

  var pixels_in_percent = dimension / 100;

  return pixels_in_percent * percent;
}


function emToPixelElementRelative(em_value, element=false) {
  var font_size = getFontSize(element);
  var ppi = getPPI();
  var px_in_pt = 72 / ppi; /* 1pt is 1/72 of an inch */
  var value_in_pt = em_value * font_size;

  return value_in_pt * px_in_pt;
}


function getFontSize(element=false) {

    if (element) {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element).fontSize);
  } else {
    /* getting font size from body */
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize);
  }
}


function getPPI() {
  var inch_div_html = "<div id='inch-div' style='height: 1in; left: -100%; position: absolute; top: -100%; width: 1in;'></div>";
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', inch_div_html);

  var device_pixel_ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  var ppi_test_div = document.getElementById('inch-div');
  var ppi = ppi_test_div.offsetWidth * devicePixelRatio;

  document.body.removeChild(ppi_test_div);

  return ppi;  
}
```

To poke it a bit, there is [demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/new93bq1/).

---

Now, a bit of explanation/remarks: `emToPixelElementRelative` and `percentToPixelElementRelative` each converts value passed to it as a first argument `em=>px` and `%=>px` respectively. Second argument to both functions (`element`) is an element, based on which dimensions, values in `px` will be calculated *(NB: keep in mind that you pass radius, not diameter to the `arc()`, which for percents means that if you'll pass a 50(%) and will base calculations on `canvas` element — diameter of the circle will be 100% and will fill the whole `canvas` (in case of square canvas))*, if the argument is not passed — values are calculated, based on a viewport's dimensions. Third argument (`width_based`) reflects if values calculated should be relative to width (if set to `true`, which is default) or height (if set to `false`).

`percentToPixelParentBased` and `emToPixelParentBased` are just wrappers for `percentToPixelElementRelative` and `emToPixelElementRelative`, which base conversion on the parent of the passed `element`.

`getFontSize` returns font size for the `element` passed, or for `<body>` element, if called without arguments.

`getPPI` is getting current PPI via, sort of, [hack mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279749/detecting-the-system-dpi-ppi-from-js-css/26004882#26004882), it accepts a single argument (`width_based`) indicating whether to base it's calculations on width (if `true` - default) or height (if `false`).

Also note, that I have based `em=>px` calculations on the following assumptions:

- font size is measured in `pt` (based on [this article](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/font-size.htm))
- `1em` is equal to the size of current font in `pt` (based on [pxtoem.com](http://pxtoem.com/#learn) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887764/8554766))
- formula for converting `pt=>px` is `1pt = 72 / ppi` (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43755222/8554766))

---

Questions (and answers to them, of course)/resources, which helped me to put this solution together:

1. Getting current PPI:

   - [how to remove HTML element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)
   - [how to insert element into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019205/8554766)
   - [general recipe of how to get current PPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26004882/8554766)
2. Getting current font size:

   - [how to get current font size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10465984/8554766)
   - [getting  HTML element (MDN wed docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body)
3. Percent to pixel conversion:

   - of course, based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43923593/8554766) above by [Magix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3753446/magix)
4. Em to pixel conversion:

   - [what is em (PXtoEM.com)](http://pxtoem.com/#learn)
   - [how em is calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887764/8554766)
   - [how to convert pt to px](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43755222/8554766)
5. Misc:

   - [answer with link to PXtoEM.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474120/8554766)
   - [difference between offsetWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth and -Height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21064102/8554766)
   - [how to make nested lists in stackoverflow markup =)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85477)